# Ubuntu on VirtualBox with bridged network cannot access the gateway or internet

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, virtualbox

I have set up a version of Ubuntu 12.04 under VirtualBox (version 4.1.18) using NAT and everything works fine (using DHCP of course).  I am running OS X Lion 10.7.4.

However, as soon as I switch the network to a Bridged Network, the Ubuntu VM experiences very odd networking problems.  The machine appears to get a DHCP address assigned just fine, but after it can only ping itself and the IP of the VM's host machine.  It cannot ping the gateway or the outside world.

I have checked lots of things:

- I have changed the network adaptor type but that makes no difference.
- I have tried rebuilding Linux from scratch, but at the start it is unable to connect to the Internet
- I've checked the network settings, and the settings are correct.  Here is a copy of ifconfig:

  ```
  eth0      
    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e4:1c:13  
    inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee4:1c13/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:33089 (33.0 KB)  TX bytes:9509 (9.5 KB)
  ```

and route -n:

```
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Please note that I am bridging my wireless port as that is the only port connected to the Internet.  I know there are supposed IPv6 limitations, but I am not using IPv6.

Thanks for any help, this has been quite frustrating to solve.

Answer (score 3):

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=45571

Most wireless adapters do not support bridged mode, and even if they do, most wireless APs do not. I suggest you check that bridging is supported in general on your host network interface. Sometimes DHCP requests can get accross, but that doesn't mean the adapter itself can handle answering to multiple IPs.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similarly problem with virtual box 4.1.18 on debian host and debian/ubuntu and windows guests. when is changed to bridged adapter my guest os didn't get an ip address with nat network connectifity was fine. after installing the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack the problem disappears

Comment: Unfortunately I already have the VM VirtualBox Extension Pack...